# Sentença while - not true... entendimento da lógica

Tags: python, while, operadores

Estou com muito problema para entender porque o programa para quando digito `n=0`.

quando digito 0 o terminou vira True, e a lógica do while é justamente esta, não?

Já rodei o programa e está correto, eu que não estou conseguindo entender. Realmente o `not` me confunde um pouco rs.

```
terminou = False
p = i = 0
while (not terminou):
    n = int(input("Digite um número, ou zero para terminar: "))
    if n == 0:
        terminou = True
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            p = p + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1

print ("P = ", p)
print ("I = ", i)
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O programa para porque o seu código determinou isso. Um primeiro lugar ele para porque ele concluiu o que tinha que fazer. Ele só consegue concluir depois que sai do laço e a condição do `while` é que determina isso.

Para entrar nele está esperando que o valor de `terminou` seja `False`. E por que tem que ser esse valor? Porque tem um operador de negação na condição, o `not`, então ele inverte o valor da variável. Se o valor é `False` ele passe ser `True` ali naquela expressão. Como o `while` espera que algo seja `True` para executar é isso que acontece, ele entra no laço.

Daí para sair só quando a passar de novo pelo o `while` e nesse momento a expressão der `False`, portanto como tem um `not` o valor de `terminou` deve ser `True`.

Qualquer valor que digite vai cair no `else` do `if` e lá o valor de `terminou` não muda. Apenas quando digitar 0 é que cai no `if` mesmo. E nesse bloco o que está mandando fazer é justamente a variável ter o valor `True`, que invertido é o que faz o laço encerrar.

Portanto é só seguir o fluxo do código que ele determina o que acontece.

Na verdade esse código ser simplificado:

```
p = i = 0
while (True):
    n = int(input("Digite um número, ou zero para terminar: "))
    if n == 0:
        break;
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            p = p + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
print ("P = ", p)
print ("I = ", i)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LJqYRe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ZeroEndspy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ZeroEnds.py).

Desta forma não precisa de variável controlando a saída e tem um comando que manda sair na hora que quiser, de forma mais explícita que quer sair, sem enrolações.

Comment: obrigada, mas o que me deu nó é que no início é determinado que a variável terminou = false. portanto se na while está como not terminou, significa que para entrar no loop espera que terminou = true ... certo?
obrigada pelo código simplificado! :)

Comment: Não, a resposta diz que é o oposto disso.